# Is it possible to have USB communication over fiber optic?

Tags: usb, fiber-optics

These fibre optic transmitters are up to 125MBd

https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-2590EN

USB 1 is 12Mbits/s
USB 2.0 is 480Mbit/s

So in theory would be possible to buy 2 of these fibre optic cables and transfer data as USB at speeds somewhere between USB 1 and 2

Would there however be problems with pulse width distortion and syncing of the lines since USB is supposed to be a differential pair?

Comment: There are lots of USB fiber optic extenders on the market, so it does appear to be possible. But there is a lot more to USB than just sending data in two directions so the design of these things probably involves a fair amount of software to replicate the USB protocol at the two ends of the link.

Comment: Sounds like a good job for a FPGA; although this significantly complicates design.

Comment: Yes, but it would be more complex than just attaching the USB data wires to a fiber optic transmitter/receiver.